# $(shell) function in GNU makefile results in 'unterminated call to function shell: missing )'

Tags: grep, gnu-make

#### Description:

I have the following snippet within my GNU makefile:

```
test:=$(shell grep '#pragma' test_types.h)
$(info test:$(test))
```

The above results in the following error message:

*** unterminated call to function 'shell': missing ')'. STOP

However if I **remove the '#'** from the snippet above:

```
test:=$(shell grep 'pragma' test_types.h)
$(info test:$(test))
```

The output is:

test: #pragma pack(push, 1) #pragma pack(pop)

If I run the following directly from the command line: `grep '#pragma' test_types.h`. The output is again:

#pragma pack(push, 1) #pragma pack(pop)

#### Question:

What is causing the shell function behaviour when combining grep with a search for `#` within a GNU makefile?

Comment: Try putting a backslash in front of the `#` because it is causing the rest of the line to be treated as a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is interpreting the `#` as the start of a comment, so the rest of the line is no longer seen.

Escape the character as `\#` instead and it will work.

Comment: It is worth a note that with Gnu Make 4.8 hashtags inside shell commands work properly while with Gnu Make 4.7 this does not work. Took me a while, so thanks for your answer :D

Comment: Edit because I had a typo in the versions: With Gnu Make 4.2 this does not work and works with Gnu Make 4.3

Comment: @PhilippPixel cursed